# installing eth-brownie with pipx

Tags: pip, path, brownie, pipx

I have been attempting to install Brownie via pipx in a Powershell terminal in VSCode (https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html). As in the link I attempted the first two commands after which the system gave me confirmation that pipx had been added to PATH:

```
python -m pip install --user pipx
python -m pipx ensurepath

...

C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts has been been added to PATH, but you need to open a new terminal or re-login for this PATH change to
    take effect.
C:\Users\Name\.local\bin has been been added to PATH, but you need to open a new terminal or re-login for this PATH change to take effect.

You will need to open a new terminal or re-login for the PATH changes to take effect.

Otherwise pipx is ready to go! ✨  ✨
```

Upon loading a new Powershell, I tried the final command as in the link, but instead got the error immediately below:

```
pipx install eth-brownie

...

pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipx install eth-brownie
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why is pipx not being recognized as a command if the output claimed it is accessible on PATH? In any case, I then tried modifying the command to include python -m at the start. My understanding is that this goes to my python program first, then accesses anything to do with pipx? It ran for a few seconds before printing a different error:

```
python -m pipx install eth-brownie

...

Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\Name\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2022-01-05_20.58.07_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build package:
    cytoolz

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I am at a loss on this error. My instinct tells me there is something wrong with my Microsoft Build Tools that I downloaded from: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/Code . But if I can resolve the first issue perhaps this is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed "pipx" from python3
if it is not installed, run

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
```

Or check env see if it is installed path
I also had the same error before, I tried with another environment from python

```
py -m pip install --user -U pipx
```

Best way to test pipx, checkin to directory :
C:\Users\...\.local
Add env
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WbIR.png)

You will need to open a new terminal or re-login for the PATH changes to take effect.

Otherwise pipx is ready to go

Comment: Make sure you restart your machine when you run the next command :3

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my machine and was able to recognize pipx at least, but upon using "pipx install eth-brownie" I got the same fatal error as at the bottom of my post. I then verified I had cython and cytoolz installed (tried pip install for each and received output stating that the requirement was already satisfied) even though the error stated "pip failed to build package: cytoolz" In the end I found some posts suggesting that pipx only works for Python 3.9. I finally tried a pip install of eth-brownie rather than pipx and that worked.

If anyone knows of any potential pitfalls of a pip rather than pipx installation of eth-brownie I would be glad to hear, but at least it was installed in the end.